# Why does my discord bot not send a variable?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a bot that needs to send a message with a set message, followed by an integer defined by a variable. When I run this, the bot reacts to the message correctly but then doesn't send any response whatsoever. Why? XD (and yes I'm kinda bad and new at coding but idc I am determined to get this to work!)
EDIT: Ok it's sending the text and variable now, but it always prints as 0. Anyone know why it's always zero?

```
else:
        emoji = '\N{Cross Mark}'
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
        await message.channel.send("You messed it up at:")
        await message.channel.send(f'{bowl_count}')
        bowl_count == int(0)
```

Comment: You can't send multiple arguments. You have to concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, you can not add a reaction that way, I would recommend doing this;

```
await message.add_reaction('')
```

As for using a valuable, you can do it using a f string:

```
text = "Hello!"
await ctx.send(f'{text}')
```

Comment: well the reaction i have does actually work XD, i'll try the other part tho

Answer (score 0):

Are you using on_message?

Also are you checking if bowl_count is equal to 0?

You don't need to provide int() unless you have a variable called 0 that's value is a string (text in quote marks)

```
else:
        emoji = '\N{Cross Mark}'
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
        await message.channel.send("YOU MESSED IT UP AT: ", bowl_count)
        bowl_count = 0
```

Other than that it looks fine.

If you are using commands, then do define an await ctx.send("TEXT") as a variable called message

Answer (score 0):

```
else:
    emoji = '\n{Cross Mark}'
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    await message.channel.send("YOU MESSED IT UP AT: " + bowl_count)
    bowl_count == int(0)
```

first, the escaped `\N` doesn't work, try `\n`

second, just use + to concatenate the strings